# Wix installation, what is <StartServices> <StopServices> standard action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am learning wix toolset for packaging

Currently I need stop the windows services before the installation and re-start the service after the installation, I know I could implement the feature with custom action, but I also notice that wix has some standard actions: StartServices StopServices

I am not sure what are these elements ??? there are very limited documents about that...could these elements help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ServiceControl element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) to start and stop services.